# varying the Einstein Hilbert action when the metric has a conformal transformation pulled out of it

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, action

This is admittadly a mathematical question; however Physicists are more likely to have an answer so here goes.

Lets say I have some action S within the context of General Relativity. We know that we vary the action with respect to $g^{\mu\nu}$. Now consider that our metric is some local conformal transformation of another metric (lets say flat space as there is arguably a physical reason for doing this then). In other words:

$$g^{\mu\nu}=e^{-2\sigma(x)}\bar{g}^{\mu\nu}$$

One gets then that the Einstein-Hilbert Action:

$$S_{EH}=\intop\left(R+L_{matter}\right)\sqrt{-g}d^{4}x$$

Then becomes:

$$S_{EH}=\intop\left[e^{-2\sigma(x)}\left(\bar{R}-6\bar{g}^{\mu\nu}\bar{\nabla}_{\mu}\bar{\nabla}_{\nu}\sigma(x)-6\bar{g}^{\mu\nu}\bar{\nabla}_{\mu}\sigma(x)\bar{\nabla}_{\nu}\sigma(x)\right)+L_{matter}\right]e^{4\sigma(x)}\sqrt{-\bar{g}}d^{4}x$$

Where the bars denote operations relative to the barred metric.

My question is how do I vary the action to obtain equations of motion? My initial Guess is something like:

$$\delta S_{EH}=e^{2\sigma}(\delta g^{\mu\nu})\frac{\delta}{\delta\bar{g}^{\mu\nu}}+\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}(\delta\sigma)\frac{\delta}{\delta\sigma(x)}+\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}(\delta\nabla\sigma)\frac{\delta}{\delta(\nabla\sigma)}+higherderivativeterms$$

In other words treating $\sigma$ and $\bar{g}^{\mu\nu}$ as independent variables (I just wrote it all together for brevity). If this is correct we now have two equations of motion where previously we had one. Is this right?

**EDIT**
I get that I should be able to substitute all of this directly in the the Einstein equation and get this same answer, but I'd be much more satisfied knowing how to do it this way as well.

Comment: In Orton's *Gravity & Strings& he has a chapter on the Einstein-Hilbert Action for several different conformal frames. The scalar he uses $K$, is such that $g_{\mu \nu} \mapsto K^\alpha g_{\mu \nu}$ with $K=\exp^{-2\phi}$ then finds the variation using Palatini's identity $\delta R_{\mu \nu \rho}^{\sigma}=+2 \nabla_{[ \mu}\delta \Gamma_{\nu ] \rho}^{\sigma}$